# Build entity property from foreign Entity Repository

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, repository, entity

I have a User Entity, who can charge his customers. The User can therefore create Invoice entities. What I want to do is being able to easily retrieve how much a user has charged, by suming invoice totals. I can easily do that in my Invoice Repository by passing $user variable to the method suming these invoices. But i'd like to store this value in the User entity, so in my twig template, I could call it with something like this : {{ app.user.chargedAmount }}

But as far as I know, I can't create a getChargedAmount() in my User entity, which would use invoice repository and set a protected $chargedAmount property.

How am I supposed to store this custom value, inside my user entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways that you could do this, neither of these would involve the repository in your entity. (There are probably a bunch more way that this could be done to be honest).

1. Assuming your user model and your invoice model are associated using a `oneToMany` you could have a method in your user model that could loop through the associated invoices and get the sum on the fly. This would mean that the current total won't be persisted to the database.

   ```
   $totalCharged = null;

   public function getTotalCharged()
   {
       if (null !== $totalCharged) {
           return $totalCharged;
       }

       $totalCharged = 0;

       foreach ($this->getInvoices() as $invoice) {
           $totalCharged += $invoice->getTotal();
       }

       return $totalCharged;
   }
   ```
2. You could set up an event listener that would listen to each time an invoice was changed (created, updated, deleted) and then update your user model with the final result. (Assuming you are using Doctrine ORM). This may require you to update your controller actions to include the events if you are not using them already.

   ```
   use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
   use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
   use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\GenericEvent;

   class UserInvoiceTotalChargedSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
   {
       protected $invoiceRepository;

       public function __construct(EntityRepository $invoiceRepository)
       {
           $this->invoiceRepository = $invoiceRepository;
       }

       public static function getSubscribedEvents()
       {
           return array(
               'acme.invoice.create' => 'updateTotalCharged',
               'acme.invoice.update' => 'updateTotalCharged',
               'acme.invoice.remove' => 'updateTotalCharged',
           );
       }

       public function updateTotalCharged(GenericEvent $event)
       {
           $invoice = $event->getSubject();

           if (!$invoice instanceof InvoiceInterface) {
           // Or Invoice if you are not using interfaces
               throw new \Exception(
                   sprintf('Invoice expected, %s provided', get_class($invoice)
               );
           }

           $user = $invoice->getUser();

           $totalCharged = $this->invoiceRepository
               ->getTotalChargedForUser($user);

           $user->setTotalCharged($totalCharged);
           // This could be moved to a separate class that performed the
           // calculation instead where you could call it like
           // $this->totalChargedCalculator->calculate($invoice->getUser());
           // Obviously this would need to be injected instead of the repository
       }
   }
   ```
3. If you just wanted to access this property in a twig template you could create a custom twig extension and call it in that. Which you would then be able to use in your template like `{{ acme_invoice_total_charged(user) }}` although this doesn't offer the same kind of portability. This (like option 1) would mean that the current total won't be persisted to the database.

   ```
   class AcmeExtension extends \Twig_Extension
   {
       protected $invoiceRepository;

       public function __construct(EntityRepository $invoiceRepository)
       {
           $this->invoiceRepository = $invoiceRepository;
       }

       public function getFunctions()
       {
           return array(
               new \Twig_SimpleFunction(
                   'acme_invoice_total_charged', 
                   array($this, 'getTotalChargedForUser')
               ),
           );
       }

       public function getTotalChargedForUser(UserInterface $user)
       {
           return $this->invoiceRepository->getTotalChargedForUser($user);
       }

       public function getName()
       {
           return 'acme_invoice_extension';
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I think i'll go with option #1. I dont need to store this value in database so option #2 seems overkill to me. And Option #3 is not portable enough, I might need this info outside a twig template, in the future. I'll have add some tests to your example #1 thought, as I want to sum only the paid invoices (status = 3). The only thing I dont like about your solution is I have to apply my filters with PHP (status, year, etc) instead of inside the db query. It looks like a bit heavy.

Comment: I'd go for number 2 to be honest but then it would only make sense if you made use of the event subscriber already. There is always the option of using a doctrine event subscriber to listen to updates to the actual entity rather than your custom events.

Answer (score 0):

In your UserRepository, you can create a custom query (for example `findChargedAmount`) that will retrieve the charged amount.

```
public function findChargedAmount($user)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT SUM(i.total) AS amount FROM MyBundle:Invoice i WHERE i.user = :user');
    $query->setParameter('user', $user);
    $sum = $query->getResult();

    return $sum[0]['amount'];
}
```

Assuming that the invoice entity as a foreign key to the user. You can also build this query using a [query builder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html).

Hope that will help you.

Comment: that's pretty much what I refer to in my original post. And the problem is this value can't be stored in the User entity (not necessarily in DB, just in PHP object). So every time I want to use it, I have to call that method instead of just calling {{ app.user.getChargedAmount }}, and pass it to my template. Moreover, i can't "cache" it, as Qoop's solution #1 does.